# Scoreboard Death caused by Players Setup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friends and I are setting up a lucky block skywars game, but it is really common to die from a lucky block, so how do I set up a death counter that would only count deaths caused by players?

I can easily change to any version so i just need a way to do this, i chose the older versions because they don't have the new PvP system as Quijibo said, and i chose 1.7.10 specifically because there are more kinds of lucky blocks atleast i think so

sorry for the inconvenience this is my first time making one of these posts

Comment: @Joachim I want to set up a death counter that would only count deaths caused by players.

Comment: @Joachim Well I want to know how to do that.

Comment: Why are you playing in 1.7.10?

Comment: What do you count as "caused by player"? Only direct hit by axe, bow, etc.?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question about 1.7.10.  That version is 5 years old, and even moving to 1.9 would make this orders of magnitude easier to accomplish.  You're unlikely to receive answers that work that far back.  You are likely to receive answers for 1.9-1.12 or 1.13 and above.

Comment: Ok, Well can i get any answers at all?

Comment: 1.7.10 has the old PvP system. Also, I figured it out. Answer coming right up.

Comment: Just removing your version doesn't change that you still need an old answer.  Unless you're using a more recent version, in which case, you need to tell us that.

Comment: I can easily change to any version so i just need a way to do this, i chose the older versions because they dont have the new PvP system as Quijibo said, and i chose 1.7.10 specifically because there are more kinds of lucky blocks atleast i think so

Comment: That's important information to add to your question.

Comment: @Coz hey, there's nothing bad about playing on an older version of Minecraft. I personally also like the old PvP system much better than the new one. I guess some people are just being a bit salty in the comments.

Comment: @Quijibo It's more that I can't imagine myself doing anything command block related in any version prior to 1.9, and would personally prefer to stay in 1.13 or later.  I'm pretty sure this can be done with a single command in 1.13 or later.  1.7 also doesn't have fill clocks, necessitating redstone, which became a huge no-no as soon as 1.8 came out.

Comment: @MBraedley That's true, but it's at least a bit refreshing to go back to an older version :) Also, I think most minigame or PvP servers like Hypixel or Mineplex still run on 1.7.10, so I guess it isn't completely irrelevant after all.

Answer (score 3):

This nostalgic contraption was hard to make, is not very pretty, but works.

First of all, create 3 scoreboard objectives: a death count, a player kill count and a dummy objective. Let's call them `ActualDeaths`, `PlayerKills` and `Deaths`:

```
/scoreboard objectives add AcutalDeaths stat.deaths

/scoreboard objectives add PlayerKills stat.playerKills

/scoreboard objectives add Deaths dummy
```

Now, onto the command blocks:

[image: Command Blocks.]

I will be referring to the command blocks on the screenshot according to the colorful blocks I assigned to them, so for example, the one on the far right is the "blue" command block (and the two command blocks on the left-most are GREEN and PURPLE, not lime and magenta).

Anyways, let's get to the commands:

The blue command block is powered by a redstone clock, and simply tests if anyone has killed a player:

```
/testfor @a[score_PlayerKills_min=1]
```

The yellow command block is powered by the same redstone clock as the blue one, and tests if anyone has died:

```
/testfor @a[score_ActualDeaths_min=1]
```

The purple command block resets the `ActualDeaths` scores, so that the comparators leading from the yellow command block are reset:

```
/scoreboard players set @a ActualDeaths 0
```

The red and green command blocks run their commands only if both the blue and yellow command blocks have passed their `/testfor` commands at once (that's why the piston is there). Here's what they do:

The red command block adds 1 `Deaths` scoreboard point to every player that has a score of `ActualDeaths` at least `1` (in other words, it gives the point to anyone that has died in the last few gametics):

```
/scoreboard players add @a[score_ActualDeaths_min=1] Deaths 1
```

The green command block resets the `PlayerKills` scoreboard, so that the blue command block's comparator is reset:

```
/scoreboard players set @a PlayerKills 0
```

That's it! Be aware that it may not be perfect and it might fail counting in all deaths in cases like two players dying in the same tick, since the only way I was testing this was by shooting myself to death by arrows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer its appreaciated

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should mark as accepted so other players can know this works :)